# Pyserial writes data but does not read

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm relatively new to programming, so bear with me. I'm trying to communicate with the measurement device METEX M-4650CR https://sigrok.org/wiki/Voltcraft_M-4650CR and I'm using a windows 7 64bit OS. I simply want to read out the data the device measures to my python procedure and display it and calculate with it.

I found in the manual http://elektron.pol.lublin.pl/elekp/labor_instr/METEX_M-4650CR_Manual.pdf (page 25ff), that it works with a **baudrate of 1200**, a **bytesize of 7** (with ASCII coding) and **2 stopbits**.

Furthermore, it can be requested to send data to the computer by simply giving it the command "M". It then returns **14 bytes** to the computer. Without anything to measured connected to it, it should return something like 'DC 00.0000V  CR'. CR is the terminator here (I hope that is the right name).

Here is my code:

```
import pyserial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=1200, 
                    bytesize=7, stopbits=2, timeout=1, 
                    rtscts=False, dsrdtr=True)

time.sleep(1)
ser.write("M")
time.sleep(1)
bytestoread = ser.inWaiting()
print bytestoread

output = ''
output += ser.read(1000)
print 'output:' + str(output)

time.sleep(1)
ser.close()
```

My problem is, that I cannot read out the data properly with pyserial. I send the command "M" to the METEX and in the display it says 'send' for a short moment, so I guess my write command works fine. But after that (it should have send the data), all I get when from `ser.inWaitung` is '0L' or '1L' and the `ser.read` command gives nothing at all.

I don't think it is a problem of the hardware, because with another programme, called 'serialwatcher', I'm able read out the data correctly. It gives exactly the characters described in the manual.

I also tried the following while loop, having the problem, that most of the time `inWaiting == 0`, such that it never initialises the loop.

```
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    output += ser.read(1)
if output != '':
    output = outpus.rstrip()
    print output
```

So, how can I read out the data correctly, that were send to the serial port? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot test your code because I have no serial device with me, but you could try the following:

You could set a flag, e.g. `alive` when you are expecting data and simply try to read something. This worked for me when I was trying to receive data from a really old spectrometer.

```
     while alive:                          #loop
        text = ser.read(1)                 #try to read one line
        if text:                           #if there is data
            n = ser.inWaiting()            #look if there is more to read
            if n:                          #if so
                text = text + ser.read(n)  #get all of it
```

A more sophisticated example can be found here [wxTerminal - Pyserial example](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/examples/wxTerminal.py) You could also simply try to modify this brilliant code for your purpose and see if you are more successful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the link is really great. Although, the problem was another one: I simply had to use "ser.setDTR(1)". I thought, the use of DTR is set when defining the port name, but it wasn't.